# headers not being sent using ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, header

Where I am wrong ?

I tried this :

```
ajax({
            async: true,
            crossDomain : true,
            type: "GET",
            headers: {
                "authorization": "xyz"
            },
            url: url})
```

I also tried this :

```
ajax({
            async: true,
            crossDomain : true,
            type: "GET",
            beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
                jqXHR.setRequestHeader('authorization', 'xyz');
            },
            url: url});
```

Comment: You're setting request headers, but looking for response headers.  Which is it?  If you're executing this code in your browser then take a look at the Network tab of your browser's debugging tools.  There you can find all the header/content/etc. information for your AJAX requests and responses.

Comment: use success attribute of jquery ajax for response instead of you used.

Comment: @David: thanks for suggesting the Network tab of your browser's debugging tools! I fixed it,it was cross domain that causing issue, allowing authorization in api helped.